# Hook action when create new category

Tags: categories, taxonomy, hooks

well I need do some things when new category is created,

I've been looking for which is the hook for this but I don't found nothing that's works.

If you can help me, thanks.

Comment: what did you already tried ? You say, "i don't found nothing that's works", so, what did you found ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hook you want is `create_{$taxonomy}`.

E.g.

```
add_action('create_category', 'my_theme_do_something', 10, 2);

function my_theme_do_something($term_id, $taxonomy_term_id){
    // do some things
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was testing with that, but it was another error in my code that made it not work.